# Inkscape - export presentation in PDF, plugin?

Tags: inkscape, presentation-design, plugin

I want to ask you if you know about way or plugin for exporting slides made in Inkscape in PDF (yea, I don't like anything like PowerPoint)? I'm making them into seperate layers. Sozi and it's tool for export not only makes it PNG first before making PDF, and also is not supported for Windows. Do you have any idea how to make it without a lot of hand-work? Thanks for any ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

See my screenshot:

[image]

In the left there's some drawn random shapes and text. They were printed as PDF. Adobe PDF is not a must. I used a low cost alternative PDFill Image Writer. I believe Foxit Reader's PDF printer or some other free PDF printer works as well.

In the right there is an imported file. The file = the just printed PDF. All objects are selected and ungrouped (see NOTE1). You see in the Objects panel that they are still vectors except the gradient. It's rasterized.

Text on the PDF is divided to separate path objects. It's no more editable text.

**Conclusion:** You do not need a plugin, only a PDF printer. Some extension script could be useful, if you want to print automatically separate layers as separate PDF pages. Unfortunately I'm not a programmer.

Separate PDF files can be combined to one in PDF editors.

NOTE1: PDFs have incredibly complex grouping. It's ungrouped with Extensions > Arrange > Deep Ungroup

Answer (score 0):

Try the extension at https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-exportobjects/tree/master - it allows to export layers as pdf files, even with a common base layer.

If you want to chain the pdf files into one, try a tool like pdfshuffler or pdfsam (or whatever is available for your operating system).

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question as I found nice and easy way, and I can't believe I didn't found it earlier. In save as dialog at the very bottom is option to save Layers as Separate SVG (tar), and then I used script I found somewhere, I don't remember where and adjusted it a bit (Windows):

`for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %i in ('dir /b *.svg') do "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --without-gui --file="%i.svg" --export-pdf="%i.pdf"`

Then I use PDFill Free to merge.

Maybe someone will have some use of it :)